# Replace NA within groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a big dataset makes as this example:

```
Test = data.frame("ID" = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,4), rep(3,5)),
                  "Value" = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.5, NA))
```

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | NA |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | NA |
| 3 | NA |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | NA |

Every ID has NAs and only one value, that can be repeated many times.
I want that every value into each group (group variable = ID) is the not null value, in the case of this example I expected this result:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 0.33 |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 |

I tried something like that:

```
Test %>% group_by(ID) %>% coalesce(Value, first(na.omit(Value)))
```

...but I receive the error: *Error in list2(...) : object 'Value' not found*

Someone can help me?

Comment: After group_by you need a mutate: `mutate(Value = coalesce(Value, first(na.omit(Value))))`

Comment: @TarJae I think they want first non-na value fill, not any neighbour value. Anyway, this should be closed as "typo".

Comment: Hmmh. I deleted but the expected output is quite good for fill()?

Comment: For this example fill might work.

Comment: But OP states: "Every ID has NAs and only one value, that can be repeated many time"

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fill` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(Value, .direction = "updown")

      ID Value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  1   
 2     1  1   
 3     1  1   
 4     2  0.33
 5     2  0.33
 6     2  0.33
 7     2  0.33
 8     3  0.5 
 9     3  0.5 
10     3  0.5 
11     3  0.5 
12     3  0.5
```